# How to achieve "where slug()" in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to map this type of route:

```
/images/united-states/san-francisco
```

In my `routes.php` file, I wrote :

```
Route::get('/images/{country_slug}/{city_slug}', 'ImageController@listByCountryAndCity');
```

And in my controller :

```
public function listByCountryAndCity($country, $city)
{
    return Image::where('country', $country)->where('city', $city)->paginate();
}
```

How can I *slug* the **country** before comparison?

And I don't want to add any other table called **Country** or **City**

Comment: Oh wait a second, do you want to unslug it? And find the record by normal title?

Comment: That would be awesome.. But it wont work everytime. The reliable way would be to slug the title and then compare the 2 sulgs (like password hashes).

Comment: @David Yeah, but you can't do that unless you fetch all entries from the table, iterate over them and then compare the _slugged_ title with the request slug, which is not an option performance wise.

Answer (score 6):

In a case like yours I'll do a route like this :

```
Route::get('/post/{id}-{slug}', 'PostController@show');
```

And in your controller :

```
public function show($id, $slug)
{
    return Post::find($id);
}
```

So the slug is just here for SEO and you only work with the `$id`

OR, you can create a scope :

```
public function scopeFindBySlug($query, $title)
{
    $query->where('slug', '=', str_slug($title));
}

Post::findBySlug($title)->first();
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can't, at least not in any reliable way.**

Because titles can contain special characters that are not URL safe, and if you were to use for example [`str_slug`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-str-slug) to generate the slug, those special characters would be removed and thus you would have no way of reconstructing the title for the query condition, because there would be missing characters.

So the only solution is to have a `slug` column in your database, which is a good solution. If you're thinking that having an extra column for the slug is redundant, **it's not**. While the title and URL slug are similar (and in this case dependent on one another) they are two separate entities and it's only logical you treat them as such.

Having a `slug` column offers the exact functionality you need, with the added benefit of having the ability to set *any* custom slug for an entry, not just one generated from the title.

Comment: Things are actually different... The routes I want to map are like `/images/united-states/1458`. And in my **Image** table I have a field called `place` which is in this case `United States`. And I don't want to add another table called **Country**.

Comment: 1. Then why is the example in your question different, is it a separate case, or just generic? 2. What is that trailing int value `1458` from the URL path?

Comment: Sorry but my answer still stands. If you would have a strict set of rules for naming, like: the country and city names you have stored in the database only contain letters, numbers or spaces (because anything else will be removed), all words are capitalized, there are no dashes (this might be impossible) and there are no places where there is more than one consecutive space character (because multiple spaces will be merged into a dash), then you could use `str_slug` to generate the URL path and be able to reliably decode the slug, otherwise you need to store the slugs separately.

Comment: My opinion is that it's way easier to make the necessary database structure changes, than to implement a restrictive way of encoding and decoding slugs, that may break in the future because of unforeseen edge cases.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up with this solution.. I added 2 other tables: Cities and Countries.

Comment: Do Eloquent have a function to retrieve all images where City = xxx and Country = yyy ? (Without using php loops and without using Query builder)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in laravel function `str_slug($string)`.

But be aware this function does not check if the slug is already taken. It just transforms your string as a slug.

Comment: Yep, I know this function.. But how to combine it with Eloquent `where` ?

Comment: As @Bogdan said, not in any reliable way. Save the slug, not bad at all. Else you have to do some heavy querying which is very bad (looping through records and slugging the field for comparison).